# how to handle properties with this FxCopAnalyzer warning: "CA2227: Set "Images" as read-only by removing the setter for the property"

Tags: vb.net

**What is this programme about:**

This program was developed with the VB.Net language, the .NET Framework 4.8 and Visual Studio 2019 CE. The idea of this program is to run a rudimentary database. The list is similar to a classic Internet forum—there are threads, there are different numbers of postings in the threads and in each post there are different numbers of pictures and long texts. If the thread is selected using the ComboBox, all posts with their images and texts are displayed one below the other. When you click on a specific post, only *its* images are displayed.

The user can create threads and posts. For reasons of legibility, only extended Latin letters are allowed when writing the text (e.g. René, Chloë).

When you close the program, you will be asked whether you want to save the data. These data are read in when the program is loaded. If images are not found, their paths will be displayed in a window.

The user also has the option of searching through all threads and viewing the results with various sorting options. In this case, only the posts found are listed in the ListBox, and here, too, the user can select the posts individually.

The program also reads in user data when it starts. A user can log in and, depending on his role, has certain power to make decisions. A “normal” user can create threads and posts, but only an administrator or moderator can edit and delete texts. If you are not logged in, you can only read threads and posts.

**What I would like to know from you**

I use the FxCopAnalyzer, which is currently giving me 8 warnings. I am aware that it sometimes exaggerates a little or criticizes certain things that were done on purpose. But I'd like to let you guys have a look to make it better. What exactly is this supposed to mean: "CA2227: Set "Images" (Bilder) as read-only by removing the setter for the property". Because when I remove the setter, I get an error message.
I feel the same way with other properties in other classes. **So I need to know, how to fix this, and I need a general solution.** I appreciate.

**Class structure**

There is the class `Forum`, the class `Class_Thread` and the class `Class_Post`. `Class_Thread` inherits from `forum`. In the `Class_thread` there is a `list(of Class_Post)` which contains instances of `Class_Post`. ("The thread knows what posts it has"). In `FormMain`, a `List(of Class_Thread)` is created, in which the instances of `Class_Thread` are.
In `Class_Post`'s constructor, the following parameters are transferred: 1) the heading of the posting, 2) the text, 3) the number, 4) images as List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap), 5) the date, 6) the image paths As List(Of String).

**Class_Post.vb**

```
#Disable Warning CA1707 ' Bezeichner dürfen keine Unterstriche enthalten
Public Class Class_Post : Inherits Class_Forum
    Private _ueberschrift As String = ""
    Private _text_dazu As String = ""
    Private _nummer As UInt16
    Private _bilder As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    Private _erstelldatum_dieses_Posts As Date
    Private _pfade_der_Bilder As List(Of String)

    Public Property Ueberschrift As String
        Get
            Return _ueberschrift
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ueberschrift = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Text_dazu As String
        Get
            Return _text_dazu
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _text_dazu = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Nummer As UShort
        Get
            Return _nummer
        End Get
        Set(value As UShort)
            _nummer = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Bilder As List(Of Bitmap)
        Get
            Return _bilder
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Bitmap))
            _bilder = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts As Date
        Get
            Return _erstelldatum_dieses_Posts
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            _erstelldatum_dieses_Posts = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Pfade_der_Bilder As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _pfade_der_Bilder
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            _pfade_der_Bilder = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Ueberschrift As String, ByVal Text As String, ByVal nr As UInt16, ByVal uebergebene_Bilder As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap), ByVal _date As Date, ByVal Pfade As List(Of String))
        Me.Ueberschrift = Ueberschrift
        Me.Text_dazu = Text
        Me.Nummer = nr
        Me.Bilder = uebergebene_Bilder
        Me.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts = _date
        Me.Pfade_der_Bilder = Pfade
    End Sub
End Class
#Enable Warning CA1707 ' Bezeichner dürfen keine Unterstriche enthalten
```

[image: warning by FxCopAnalyzer]

**This is in FormMain, where a new Instance of Class_Post is created** This Sub is using a second Form from which the data is taken.

```
Private Sub Button_neueAntwort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_neueAntwort.Click
        ' doppelt abgesichert, falls die Variable SI aus irgendeinem Grunde nicht (-1) ist, obwohl sie das sollte.
        If SI <> (-1) OrElse ComboBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Using FA As New Form_Antwort
                Dim DR As DialogResult = FA.ShowDialog(Me)
                If DR = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    Dim neuerPost As New Class_Post(FA.Titel_des_Posts, FA.Beschreibung, CUShort(Liste_mit_allen_Threads(SI).Posts_in_diesem_Thread.Count + 1), FA.NeueListeBitmaps, Date.Now, FA.Liste_mit_Pfaden)
                    Liste_mit_allen_Threads(SI).Posts_in_diesem_Thread.Add(neuerPost)
                    
                    alle_Posts_in_diesem_Thread_anzeigen()
                End If
            End Using
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Bitte zuerst einen Thread auswählen.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Most commonly, when a `List(Of T)` is a class member, clients of the list are operating on the list rather than swapping an entirely different object in for it.  For those cases, it makes sense to declare the property as `Public ReadOnly Property Foo As List(Of Bar) = New List(Of Bar)`.  Note that in general, modern VB allows property declarations to be much more compact than they were in the past---none of your property declarations as shown need an explicit body.

Comment: @Craig Thanks, but then I can't fill the list using the constructor. ?

Comment: @craig "none of your property declarations as shown need an explicit body." That's a thing the FxCopAnalyzer suggested to make, too. 

Comment: You can still change the underlying object in the ctor if you want.  You can access the underlying variable (VB will have an implicit `_Foo` variable in my example), and you may even be able to write through the property in the ctor, I don't remember if VB lets you do that.  (C# definitely will allow it, but C# doesn't have the implicit variable to use for access that VB has.)

Comment: You're setting the Properties (you should set the backing Field, unless you need a *cascading effect* generated by the setters) in the Constructor. This makes assume that the Property values are Read-Only after. This may not be the case, the warning is for your convenience, it may be a mistake on your part. -- If you set the backing Field as Read-Only, you need to remove the Setter and make the Property itself `ReadOnly`. As mentioned, none of these properties seem to need a backing Field, but that's up to you. -- Remove the underscores, not used to name Fields.

Comment: @Jimi the underscores are a reasonable naming convention for module- or class-level private variables.

Comment: @Craig It depends. I what language? The underscore has a specific meaning. Not that it counts, but, for example, I cannot even write a Field name like that when I code *officially*, it's a violation of the naming conventions (which are quite strict when I code for real), so it's an error, not a warning. -- Of course others can have different naming conventions. I understand that using standard `camelCase` only in a case-insensitive language may not be wise all the time, but I wrote *underscores* (plural). The leading one could do, the others make it less readable (opinion? possibly).

Comment: @jimi do you mean it like this? ```Public Class Class_Post : Inherits Class_Forum
    Public ReadOnly Property Ueberschrift As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Property Text_dazu As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Property Nummer As UInt16
    Public ReadOnly Property Bilder As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    Public ReadOnly Property Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts As Date
    Public ReadOnly Property Pfade_der_Bilder As List(Of String)```

Comment: Yes, like that (you could have posted just one as sample :), with a `ReadOnly` Field (if you want to keep the Fields -> in case the setters need to do something specific, or, e.g., if you plan on implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` later etc.). Of course, you then set the Field in the Constructor, not the Property. If you only have auto-implemented Properties, then of course you set the Property (the backing Field is still there, just *hidden* and that's what the auto-implemented Property sets under the hood).

Comment: @Jimi Sorry, I misunderstood the concern you were raising.  I agree that snake case is not the typical naming convention in .NET code.

Comment: Ok, I understand your tips and that you mean it well. Unfortunately, I've got used to this because I'm also active in German forums, where I am told again to please use underscores (snake_case) (at least for names with more than 20 characters. By the way: the same people remove the vowels in every name). If the naming convention dictates that, I'll rename the variables. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi and Craig, I can come up with a solution here. The thing is, unfortunately I let the FxCopAnalyzer influence me a bit. It had suggested using getters and setters instead of the normal fields, and that's why the warning I reported about came up. But the solution looks very simple, just use **properties**:

```
Public Class Class_Post : Inherits Class_Forum
    Public ReadOnly Property Ueberschrift As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Property Text_dazu As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Property Nummer As UInt16
    Public ReadOnly Property Bilder As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    Public ReadOnly Property Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts As Date
    Public ReadOnly Property Pfade_der_Bilder As List(Of String)


    Public Sub New(ByVal Ueberschrift As String, ByVal Text As String, ByVal nr As UInt16, ByVal uebergebene_Bilder As List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap), ByVal _date As Date, ByVal Pfade As List(Of String))
        Me.Ueberschrift = Ueberschrift
        Me.Text_dazu = Text
        Me.Nummer = nr 'kann maximal 65535 werden
        Me.Bilder = uebergebene_Bilder
        Me.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts = _date
        Me.Pfade_der_Bilder = Pfade
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Edit:**
Of course, this is only true until you decide to create a button where a moderator wants to delete an image. Then, `ReadOnly` has to be removed again and the FxCopAnalyzer complains again.

Comment: You still might have missed the point of the warning, you don't have to remove ReadOnly.  The list can't be replaced but the *content* of the list can.

Comment: Yes I do because I always pass a List(of..) as parameter. I guess you want me to write ``` Public ReadOnly Property Bilder As NEW List(Of System.Drawing.Bitmap)``` and to pass Images one by one and add them to the List, right? But I can't know how many are coming ... and, like that, I never can delete ones (or?)